# Jquery replace text live doesn't works

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace, wysiwyg

this is my js.

```
$('.wysiwyg').live('keyup',function(){

     wysiwyg_val = $(this).val();

    wysiwyg_val = wysiwyg_val
    .replace(/\n/g, "<br />")
    .replace(/\n\n+/g, '<br /><br />')
    .replace("{code}","<pre><code>")
    .replace("{/code}","</code></pre>")
    .replace("{img}",'<img src="http://localhost/CI_DEVBASE/img/logo.png" width="150" height="50"')
    .replace("{/img}",'/>');

    $('.wysiwyg-preview').html(wysiwyg_val);


  });
```

the html is.

```
<textarea class="wysiwyg"></textarea>
<div class="wysiwyg-preview"></div>
```

this code works if i put just 1 `{code}{/code}` inside the textarea, but if i put 2 `{code}{/code} {code}{/code}` it replaces only the first one, how can i apply this function to all the text inside `wysiwyg_val` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`g` should be used for `global` replacement. Also I have used `\` to escape special characters like `{`,`/` etc. Here's the corrected code for you:

```
wysiwyg_val = wysiwyg_val
    .replace(/\n/g, "<br />")
    .replace(/\n\n+/g, '<br /><br />')
    .replace(/\{code\}/g,"<pre><code>")
    .replace(/\{\/code\}/g,"</code></pre>")
    .replace(/\{img\}/g,'<img src="http://localhost/CI_DEVBASE/img/logo.png" width="150" height="50"')
    .replace(/\{\/img\}/g,'/>');
```

Comment: do you know how i can edit this code to replace in case of {code}{type=plain-text} to <code class="plain-text"><pre> ? :P

Answer (score 1):

Hej Ispuk

you already have the solution in your code

```
.replace(/\n/g, "<br />")
```

the g tels it to do it globally. Use the same technique with the code blocks.